# Polynomial approximation and limit under integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity, operator-theory

Assume $f\in C(K)$ is a continuous function on a compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $p_n$ be a sequence of polynomials converging to $f$ so that also their derivatives converge, i.e.,  $p_n^{(m)}\rightarrow f^{(m)}$ for each $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Given is a linear operator $A:C(K)\rightarrow C(K)$. Under which condition one has the following equality

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{K}A(p_n^{(m)})(x)dx = \int_{K}A(f^{(m)})(x)dx \; \; \; \; m\in\mathbb{N}?$$

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: What is $K$? Convergence in which sense?

Comment: Sure about uniform convergence? $C(\mathbb R)$ with the topology of uniform convergence is not even a topological vector space. Do you mean perhaps $A:C^\infty(\mathbb R) \to C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ where this space is endowed with the topology of uniform convergence of all derivatives on all compact subsetes of $\mathbb R$? In any case, you have to arrange you question so that the integrals exist in some sense.

Comment: K now is a proper compact set see the edited version.

Comment: @stochastic_name_here OK, but what does $p_n^{(m)}\to f^{(m)}$ mean? Pointwise convergence, uniform convergence, $L^1$, $L^2$?

Comment: this is not a fixed point so you can choose it so that you can answer the question.